# Pandas Groupby - select row with highest value in one column if multiple rows exceed value in another

Tags: python, pandas

This operation groups my DataFrame by two columns, then returns the row with the highest value in `ColumnC`:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(['columnA', 'columnB'], sort=False)['columnC'].idxmax()]
```

Instead, for all rows where `ColumnC > 100` within each group, I would like to take the row with the highest value in `ColumnD`.

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

Comment below by @Code Different is basically what I'm looking for, but I don't want to exclude groups where none of the rows have `ColumnC > 100`, in these cases I want the row with the highest value in `ColumnC`, as in the example above.

Comment: `idx = df[df['columnC'] > 100].groupby(['columnA', 'columnB'])['columnD'].idxmax(); df.loc[idx]`?

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but I don't want to exclude any groups where none of the rows have `ColumnC > 100`, which I believe your solution does.

Comment: So what do you want to output for these groups, n/a?

Comment: Good question, sorry for being unclear - just return the row with the largest value in `ColumnC` in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we split the data by two part , then filter them after the condition

```
df=sort_values('columnD')

df1 = df[df['columnC'] > 100]].drop_duplicates(['columnA', 'columnB'],keep='last')
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['columnA', 'columnB'],keep='last')

Yourdf=pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['columnA', 'columnB'])
```

Comment: This is returning the same df as this line `df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(['columnA', 'columnB'], sort=False)['columnC'].idxmax()]`